# What it is the Grep to remove all lines BUT, name and country

Tags: regex, grep

My file has this following pattern.

```
 [
{
    "id": 8050879,
    "coord": { "lon": -1.65825, "lat": 42.808472 },
    "country": "ES",
    "geoname": { "cl": "P", "code": "PPLL", "parent": 6359749 },
    "name": "Iturrama",
    "stat": { "level": 1.0, "population": 24846 },
    "stations": [
      { "id": 5493, "dist": 4, "kf": 1 },
      { "id": 28697, "dist": 32, "kf": 1 }
    ],
    "zoom": 14
  },
{
    "id": 5406990,
    "coord": { "lon": -122.064957, "lat": 37.906311 },
    "country": "US",
    "geoname": { "cl": "P", "code": "PPL", "parent": 5339268 },
    "langs": [
      { "bg": "Уолнът Крийк" },
      { "de": "Walnut Creek" },
      { "en": "Walnut Creek" },
      { "eo": "Walnut Creek" },
      { "link": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walnut_Creek%2C_California" },
      { "post": "94595" }
    ],
    "name": "Walnut Creek",
    "stat": { "level": 1.0, "population": 64173 },
    "stations": [
      { "id": 374, "dist": 9, "kf": 1 },
      { "id": 10103, "dist": 9, "kf": 1 },
    ],
    "zoom": 11
  },
...
]
```

I would like to get

```
[
{
 "country": "ES",
"name": "Iturrama"
},
{
 "country": "US",
"name": "Walnut Creek"
},
...
]
```

I have been using
grep -v id filename > result
then
grep -v coord result > result
grep -v geoname result > result
... 
until I get my pattern, but I noticed I am deleting anything that has id on it,
So If I have a name: "cIDadel" it will delete too.

Can any one help me with that?

Comment: Why use `grep`? Use a proper JSON parser like `jq`. Are you open to solutions using it? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use non-syntax aware tools like `grep` to parse structured data like JSON. It can't possibly differentiate the underlying types i.e. object/array or any other. Use a proper parser like `jq` using which you can simply do

```
jq 'map({country, name})' json_file
```

See it work in [jq-playground](https://jqplay.org/s/Oqn_iUCber). Downloading instructions and setting up is pretty easy - [Download jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use shell tools for some reason instead of JSON parsing, use AWK.
file.awk

```
/^\[$/ {print($0)}
/^\{$/ {print($0)}
/"country"/ {print($0)}
/"name"/ {print($0)}
/^ *\},$/ {print($1)}
/^\]$/ {print($0)}
```

Call:

```
awk -f file.awk yourdata.txt
```